# Using variable from one component to another component without using props

Tags: reactjs

I have a component `YourInformation`:

```
class YourInformation extends React.Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        errors: {},
        username:"",
        alterEGO:"",
        aboutYou:"",
        stage:1,
        blocking: false,
        canSubmit: false
    };

    /**** binding to make context of this to class ***/
    this.formValueChange = this.formValueChange.bind(this);
    this.disableButton = this.disableButton.bind(this);
    this.enableButton = this.enableButton.bind(this);
    this.submitInformation = this.submitInformation.bind(this);
}

/**** function to handle change in form inputs ****/
formValueChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.target.id == 'username') {
      this.state.username = event.target.value;
    } else if (event.target.id == 'alterEGO') {
      this.state.alterEGO = event.target.value;
    } else if (event.target.id == 'aboutYou') {
      this.state.aboutYou = event.target.value;
    }

    return true;
}

/**** function to handle submit event ****/

submitInformation() {

    let _that = this;
    _that.setState({ blocking: true});

    /***** fetch API for your information starts **********/

    fetch(Constants.SERVER_URL + '/api/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username: this.state.username,
            alterEGO: this.state.alterEGO,
            aboutYou: this.state.aboutYou,
            stage: this.state.stage,
        }),
}).then(function (response) {
```

And one more component i.e.,

```
class ProfileInformation extends React.Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
          errors: {},
          customUrl:"",
          facebookLink:"",
          youtubeLink:"",
          instagramLink:"",
          twitterLInk:"",
          coverPic:"",
          profilePic:"",
          stage:3,
          categories:[],
          blocking: false,
          canSubmit: false
    };

    /**** binding to make context of this to class ***/
    this.formValueChange = this.formValueChange.bind(this);
    this.disableButton = this.disableButton.bind(this);
    this.enableButton = this.enableButton.bind(this);
    this.submitProfile = this.submitProfile.bind(this);
    this.getCategories = this.getCategories.bind(this);
```

}

I would like to access "username, alterEGO, aboutYOU" from `yourInformation` to `ProfileInformation` as I need these values prefilled in the `profileInformation` component form.

How can I fix this issue without using props, as I can not call `ProfileInformation` component into `YourInformation` component's `render` method?

Comment: It's unclear that you're approaching the problem the right way (the requirement not to use props) ... the data sharing architecture in React can be confusing, but you probably want a parent component that manages the data to both `yourInformation` and `ProfileInformation` and sends it to them as props.

Comment: But I am having these two separate components there is no parent component for them. And as per my requirement I need to use values from one to another component. Is there a possible way to do this ?

Comment: What keeps you from just writing a parent component? Note that components do not need to have a visual representation in the DOM. They can also just be data containers that provide data as props to its children.

Comment: If that is your hard requirement, then there is no way I know of in React to pass data from one component to another ... React does this via parent components passing props down to the children...

Answer (score 1):

React doesn't really work this way. In react you want to have the data in *the lowest parent possible* that will use the information. So basically if you have 2 components working on the same data, this data should be managed by **the parent component** of these 2, and sent via props to both the components. I recommend you read the react [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) for further understanding.

If you want to access the data globally, I would complement your project with redux. Redux allows you to have a general store on the application that stores all the data, and you can access it from many components since it's stored on the whole application not just in a single component.